# Can't remove “For development purposes only” label from my Google Maps

Tags: maps

I’m having trouble removing the “For development purposes only” label from my Google Maps, even though it’s been functioning well for years. I’ve checked everything I know and even added a new credit card, but the label remains.

I would appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you!

I Made sure it’s linked to a credit card